# Cannot Unlock Bootloader on Fairphone 4

Tags: fastboot, bootloader, fairphone-4

I have been attempting to install /e/ OS on a Fairphone 4 in accordance with these instructions: https://doc.e.foundation/devices/FP4/install and I am stuck on Step 6 of **Unlocking the Bootloader**. No matter what I do, I get results like this when attempting to use the `fastboot flashing ...` commands:

```
./fastboot flashing get_unlock_ability
FAILED (remote: 'Unrecognized command flashing get_unlock_ability')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

I've gone through multiple Troubleshooting guides. None have helped. Here are some of the notable details and things I have tried:

- I've tried on both MacOS and Windows, the result is the same.
- I've tried multiple different USB-C cables with both MacOS and Windows.
- I've tried installing the tools using Homebrew on Mac, then uninstalled, and installed using the official Android Studio process. The result is still the same.
- I've gone through and switched out the default driver on Windows for the Google one, as recommended here: https://www.reddit.com/r/fairphone/comments/slk2qd/e_installtion_troubleshooting_guide_fastboot/ the result is still the same.
- ADB works perfectly.
- The device "lists" perfectly:

  ```
  ./adb devices -l
  List of devices attached
  XXXXXXXX               device usb:2097152X product:FP4eea model:FP4 device:FP4 transport_id:14
  ```
- I have done the OEM unlock process.
- Fastboot can clearly see the device when I boot to fastboot (`./adb reboot fastboot`):

  ```
  ./fastboot devices
  XXXXXXXX      fastboot
  ```
- Version information in case it helps

  ```
  ./fastboot --version
  fastboot version 33.0.2-8557947
  Installed as /Users/XXXXXXXX/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/fastboot
  ```

I'm clearly missing something, but I've gone over the instructions and various troubleshooting guides in detail and I cannot figure out what I missed. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You are in the wrong `fastboot`, `fastbootd` (with the d at the end!) is [fastboot in userspace](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/fastbootd), what you want is the *"real"* fastboot also called bootloader.
>
> Either select *"Reboot to bootloader"* in fastboot**d** or reboot the phone with `fastboot reboot bootloader`.

Thx @ [hirnsushi](https://forum.fairphone.com/t/unknown-command-issue-w-fastbootd-solved/84559)

Comment: OK, but that introduces a different issue, when I go into the "real fastboot" (it does indeed say "FastBoot Mode" rather than FastbootD at the top) I cannot execute any commands. When I run `fastboot devices` it just hangs and never returns. Is it an issue if the FastBoot Mode screen says "Device State - locked" at the bottom?

Comment: nvm... apparently `fastboot devices` doesn't work, but `fastboot flash unlock` works just fine. Thank you!

Comment: that's strange. is it reproducable?